# Testing whether a number (N) is prime or not can be made very fast but it will require storage space

Tags: primes

Testing whether a number (N) is prime or not can be made very fast but it will require storage space.

If there is a central repository that stores all prime numbers found till now and if there is a webAPI that returns these numbers or one/few number(s) at a time (sequentially) then it will be very fast to test whether a number (N) is prime or not because now it will be just a simple lookup in the prime numbers file(s) to see whether the number (N) exists in these file(s) or not. The look up will be till the first number greater than N.

If the number (N) exists in these file(s), then it is a prime number else not.

What do people think about my algorithm?

Comment: Suppose we're interested in testing for primality 512 bit numbers. How many 512 bit primes are there? Is it feasible to store all of them?

Answer (score 2):

It would be pointless. A well implemented sieve can find prime numbers much faster than you could ever download them.

Now creating a sieve storing a large number of primes will make trial division faster, since only about $2\cdot \sqrt n / \ln n$ divisions will be needed in the worst case.

But for large n primality testing can be done much faster, and so can factoring.

About your other answers: There are billions and billions of 1024 bit numbers that have been proven to be primes (needed in cryptography). Now divide billions and billions by 2^1024 and you see there is no chance that a random 1024 bit integer has ever been checked for primality. And worlds total storage capacity (which is a ridiculous number of gigabytes per person) is not enough to store all 22 digit primes.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is no good.  It is not feasible to store all the prime numbers, or all prime numbers of a reasonable size (e.g., 1024 bits).  That would require more storage than there are atoms in the universe.

Comment: Moreover, the prime number theorem tells us that the number of primes less than $\sqrt{N}$ is $\Theta(\frac{\sqrt{N}}{\log N})$, so in the worst case you're only gaining a $\log N$ factor on the number of divisibility tests.

Answer (score -1):

The algorithm mentioned in the question has a storage problem (the required storage is not available as of now and I don't think it will be available in future also), otherwise, this algorithm is the fastest - because only a lookup in the prime number file(s) is required to find whether a number (N) is prime or not (lookup till first prime number > N) and no divisions have to be done by all the prime numbers which are less than sqrt(N)).

The algorithm mentioned in the question can be effectively used by storing 1 billion 2048 bit prime numbers (in a central repository) to be used by encryption and cryptographic algorithms. Encryption and cryptographic algorithms can save time by getting prime numbers from this repository instead of calculating their own.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150419/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-testing-whether-a-number-n-is-prime-or-not-can); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.